# Could a vacuum airship be possible?

Tags: pressure

[According to Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_airship) a **vacuum airship** is a hypothetical airship that is evacuated instead of using a lighter gas. Really, once I first saw this, I thought, "Why did I never think about this before?!" Indeed, whenever I pictured an evacuated container, I thought it would just sit there. 
 But *no*. Instead here on Earth, a theoretical vacuum airship could lift 1.28 grams per liter of evacuated space, a 14% boost over helium, owing to the density of air.

Of course, the air is also the destroyer of this powerful capability; it exerts 14 psi, or ~0.1 MPa!! According to Wikipedia's calculations, a hemispherical shell would have to withstand $$450,000 kg^{-1} m^5 s^{-2}$$ which is over 3 times the buckling pressure of diamond.

Give up? Not yet. There is a couple of interesting ideas I thought about:

1. Why hemispherical? Wouldn't other shapes do well also? For example, a sphere, or a cylinder (maybe a cylinder with radius=height). From what I know (not much..) about spherical items, I suppose it would distribute the pressure evenly. Wouldn't that mean that diamond could easily sustain 100 kPa (withstands up to 600 GPa)?
2. Is there no other way around this obstacle? Could we make use of any exotic forces or structural methods? 
   (One interesting suggestion: Gradually evacuate the helium-filled airship, slowly going up, so that when we reach a total vacuum the airship is basically in space? In that case there wouldn't be any powerful pressure from air...)

Comment: I you have answers, you may ask this question here http://physics.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195122/could-a-vacuum-airship-be-possible?noredirect=1#comment416256_195122 @Shadock

Comment: I'm closing this question since it is cross-posted to [physics.se](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195122/) where it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Ok!